# Rails escape_javascript is not rendering stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
$('#new_post').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $('.posts').append("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>'post', :loca\
ls=>{:post=>Post.new})%>");
    });
});
```

which results in a bizarre output, the page simply append `<%=escape_javascript(render :partial=>'post', :locals=>{:post=>Post.new})%>` to my list.

Does anyone know how this could happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem eventually, thanks!

Actually I used that approach first, but it didn't work.

So it turns out I used

```
format.js { render :nothing => true }
```

in my controller, which will probably prevent javascript from rendering anything.

Besides, instead of using

```
<%= div_for post do %>
```

I used

```
<tr><td>
```

format
for my single post
and I guess that's part of reason why my javascript doesn't work

now my create.js.erb only renders

```
$('#posts').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@post)) %>");
```

and it works.

Thank you guys, I am new to this community (also rails/javascript) but I have learned a lot already.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a partial or a view, make sure it is named with the extension `.js.erb` or you may not get the proper ERB interpolation happening.

Comment: You mean 'post' (post.js.erb)? I put the code above in application.js, it works for my 'delete', so I assume the same approach should work for 'create'.

Comment: If you have ERB in your JavaScript, you cannot put it in `public/application.js` since this is sent directly to the browser without interpolation. What you need is to create a route to an action where you return the proper interpolated script.